# Rails: Preselect a value in ActionView-Helper 'collection_select'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actionviewhelper

I'm trying to get the [ActionView-Helper `collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001910) to take a value that will be preselected in the dropdown-menu.

Neither (`:selected` in the html-option-hash)

```
<%= collection_select(:my_object, :my_method, @my_collection, :id, :description_string, {}, {:selected => @my_collection_object.id}) %>
```

nor (`:selected` in the option-hash)

```
<%= collection_select(:my_object, :my_method, @my_collection, :id, :description_string, {:selected => @my_collection_object.id}, {}) %>
```

seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001910):

Sample usage (selecting the associated `Author` for an instance of `Post`, `@post`):

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial)
```

If `@post.author_id` is already 1, this would return:

```
<select name="post[author_id]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">D. Heinemeier Hansson</option>
  <option value="2">D. Thomas</option>
  <option value="3">M. Clark</option>
</select>
```

So you just need to make sure that `@my_object.my_method` returns a value that matches one of the available option values. If there's a match then that option will be selected.

Comment: I accepted this answer, though I just noticed that I had to switch from collection_select to select. I had two collection selects to choose two different "post.author_id" (using the example above) so I can compare them on the page. I had a javascript-observer on each of those collection_selects and it wouldn't work because collection_selects always outputs the following html-element-id: post_author_id. My implementation doesn't work because the html-element-id of the two collection_select is identical.

Comment: Yes, the fact that Rails doesn't guarantee unique elements IDs is a bit of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001910), if `@my_object.my_method` has the same value as one of the options, that one will be selected by default.

Conversely, you could try using [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001913) in conjunction with [`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002015):

```
<%= select_tag 'my_object[my_method]', options_from_collection_for_select(@my_collection, :id, :description_string, @my_collection_object.id) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `:selected_value`

```
%= collection_select(:my_object, :my_method, @my_collection, :id, :description_string, {}, {:selected_value => @my_collection_object.id}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if @my_object.my_method returns nil. If it does,

> If calling method returns nil, no selection is made without including :prompt or :include_blank in the options hash.

Other than that, you can try using lambda, like in the rdoc example

```
{:disabled => lambda {|category| category.archived? }
```

In your case this will look like

```
{:selected => lambda {|obj| obj.id == @my_collection_object.id }}
```

Answer (score -1):

It also works if your collection is in the form of an array of 2-value arrays:

```
CURRENCIES = [["USD", "$"], ["BRL", "R$"]]

<%= collection_select :thing, :currency, CURRENCIES, :first, :last %>
```

The `:first` and `:last` trick works quite nicely for these things, without having to define a separate model for them.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question about how to select a certain value